# Google signin not working in React native expo app

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

We are trying to sign in the user to his google account from react native expo app. When user enters the google credentials, it is verified but it does not redirect to our app. The app is in development phase.

App.json file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "ReviewLite",
    "slug": "ReviewLite",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scheme":"reviewlite",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
​
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
​
       
      
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png" 
    }
  }
}
```

GoogleLogin.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";



const CLIENT_ID =
  "myclientid";
const AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
const REDIRECT_URI = "https://us-central1-reviewlite-de069.cloudfunctions.net/oauthCallback";

const GoogleLogin = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();





  const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const authUrl = `${AUTH_URL}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
        REDIRECT_URI
      )}&response_type=token&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage`;

      const { type, url } = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(
        authUrl,
        REDIRECT_URI
      );

      if (type === "success" && url) {
        // Extract the access token from the URL
        const token = url.split("#")[1].split("&")[0].split("=")[1];

        // Now you have the access token to make requests to Google Business API.
        console.log("Access Token:", token);

        // Fetch user's businesses using the token and store them in your app's state or context.
        const businesses = await fetchUserBusinesses(token);
        // Display the business selection screen with the list of businesses.
        navigation.navigate("BusinessSelection", { businesses });
      } else {
        console.error("Error during Google login:", type);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during Google login:", error);
    }
  };

  // Handle incoming custom URLs
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleCustomURL = async (event) => {
      const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();

      // Check if the URL matches your custom scheme
      if(url && url.startsWith(REDIRECT_URI)) {

        // Handle the custom URL as needed
        // You can parse the URL and perform actions based on the parameters
        // For example, you can extract data from the URL
        const data = url.split(REDIRECT_URI)[1];
        console.log('Custom URL data:', data);
      }
    };
handleCustomURL();
    // Add a listener to handle incoming custom URLs when the app is already open
    Linking.addEventListener('url', handleCustomURL);

    // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleCustomURL);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleGoBack = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome to Google Business Login</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={handleGoogleLogin}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login with Google</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleGoBack} style={styles.goBackButton}>
        <Text style={styles.goBackText}>Go Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#EAEAEA",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#4285F4",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  goBackButton: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  goBackText: {
    color: "#4285F4",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default GoogleLogin;
```

We tried to fix this issue by changing the redirect url but nothing works.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look into react-native [auth](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage) module